# Exclude type element from marshalled generic type in Moxy

Tags: java, generics, jaxb, moxy, xmltransient

I am marshalling an object to json using Moxy 2.5.1. The object extends a generic class. I don't want the type element output, so I tried following the example at http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html.

That procedure works if the class marked @XmlTransient is not generic, but if it is generic, the type element is always output.

Here's an admittedly artificial example:

```
public class AB {
    @XmlElement
    String a = "A";
    @XmlElement
    String b = "B";
}

@XmlTransient
public class Value {
    @XmlElement
    @XmlPath(".")
    AB value = new AB();
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Record extends Value {
    @XmlElement
    int id = 1;
}
```

I marshal a record using the following code:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext =
    org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
        .createContext(
            new Class[]{ Record.class, AB.class}, null);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
Record record = new Record();
marshaller.marshal(record, System.out);
```

and get the following output:

```
{"a":"A","b":"B","id":1}
```

Now if I try the following:

```
@XmlTransient
public class ValueGeneric<T> {
    @XmlElement
    @XmlPath(".")
    T value;
}

@XmlRootElement
public class RecordAB extends ValueGeneric<AB> {
    @XmlElement
    int id = 1;
}
```

with the marshalling code (basically the same as above but registering RecordAB.class):

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext =
    org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
        .createContext(
            new Class[]{RecordAB.class, AB.class}, null);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
RecordAB recordAB = new RecordAB();
recordAB.value = new AB();
marshaller.marshal(recordAB, System.out);
```

it marshals as:

```
{"type":"ab","a":"A","b":"B","id":1}
```

I want it to marshal like the first one, without the type element.

I don't need to unmarshal, so it's OK if the type information gets lost.

Something similar happens if I output XML; the root element for RecordAB has the following attributes set:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ab"
```

Anyone have an idea of how to prevent the type element from being output?

Comment: I can't repeat your generic test. Can you update with the code you used to test with your generic class?

Comment: Code updated to add code used to test with the generic class. Thanks.